# Py2exe creates exectable that does not run

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I have written a python program and want to generate an executable for it. I normally use py2exe. I have a python script with all the parameters that py2exe will take in. It generates the executable, including the images, libraries, dll's etc... with no error. When I try running the executable, nothing starts up and there is no error printed to the log.

Note I can run my Python script normally... Has anyone experienced this kind of scenario before? Where can I look to find more information on my problem when there is no debug messages available in log?